# Can Autofixture enumerate all objects given a list of possible values for each property

Tags: c#, tdd, autofixture

I'm in the middle of TDD-ing a business class that can filter objects depending on their properties. The filtering rules are numerous, each often taking into account multiple properties.

I started checking each rule by providing an enumeration of all objects properties they are filtered by, but this is getting quickly uninteresting and I would like to address the pain before my brain is eaten by "copy-paste degenerescence".

AutoFixture *should* be very helpful in this situation, but I cannot find the information in either the FAQ or the CheatSheet. Ploeh's blog [populated lists](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/08/CreatinggeneralpopulatedlistswithAutoFixture/) looked promising but didn't go in depth enough for me.

So, given the following class

```
public class Possibility
{
    public int? aValue {get;set;}
    public int? anotherValue {get;set;}
}
```

can I get a list of `Possibility` where each class contains one possible enumeration of predefined values `aValue` and `anotherValue`? For example, given the values `[null, 10, 20]` for `aValue` and `[null, 42]` for `anotherValue`, I would be returned 6 instances of `Possibility`.

If not how could I get this behavior outside of coding it myself for each object type?

Comment: There would be 3 instances of `Possibility`.

Comment: I was thinking more of an enumeration as in the couples -> null,null | null,42 | 10,null | 10,42 | ... but I'm thinking I see how the `Generator` you proposed can be modified to do this

Comment: You can do that too – you'll have to modify the internal Queues of the `PossibilityCustomization` and then replace `Take(3)` with `Take(6)` in the Generator instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the values from the question:

- `null`, `10`, `20`  for `aValue`
- `null`, `42`, `--` for `anotherValue`

Here is one way to do this with AutoFixture, using [`Generator<T>`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Generator.cs):

```
[Fact]
public void CustomizedAutoFixtureTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(
        new PossibilityCustomization());

    var possibilities = 
        new Generator<Possibility>(fixture).Take(3);

    // 1st iteration
    // -------------------
    // aValue       | null
    // anotherValue | null 

    // 2nd iteration
    // -------------------
    // aValue       | 10
    // anotherValue | 42

    // 3rd iteration
    // -------------------
    // aValue       | 20
    // anotherValue | (Queue is empty, generated by AutoFixture.)
}
```

Internally the `PossibilityCustomization` uses the [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) class to supply predefined values – when it runs out of predefined values it uses AutoFixture.

```
private class PossibilityCustomization : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly Queue<int?> aValues = 
                 new Queue<int?>(new int?[] { null, 10, 20 });

    private readonly Queue<int?> anotherValues =
                 new Queue<int?>(new int?[] { null, 42 });

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi != null)
        {
            if (pi.Name == "aValue" && aValues.Any())
                return aValues.Dequeue();

            if (pi.Name == "anotherValue" && anotherValues.Any())
                return anotherValues.Dequeue();
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat! I guess Autofixture knows how to find the `PossibilityCustomization` through a convention-based resolution (ie `[ClassName]Customization`), but how could I register one single `ISpecimenBuilder` to many classes (in case of inheritance, for example)?

Comment: You'll have to modify the `Create` method. The above `ISpecimenBuilder` looks for the property names. You can make it more general – you can also make it more specific – you can also use many `ISpecimenBuilder` instances at the same time :)

Comment: Ah ok, it is not specific to the `Possibility` class, any class created using the Generator would go through the Create call for its properties. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You *can* make it more specific though.

Answer (score 4):

AutoFixture generates [Anonymous Values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2008/11/17/anonymous-variables.aspx), so when you already have exact values you want to combine, it may not be the right tool for exactly that job.

If you're on NUnit, you can do this instead:

```
[Test]
public void HowToGetPermutations(
    [Values(null, 10, 20)] int? aValue,
    [Values(null, 42)] int? anotherValue)
{
    // Test and assert
}
```

This will run this test method six times - one for each possible permutation.

It's one of the few features I'd wish xUnit.net had, but it doesn't...

Comment: I was aware of the combinatorials capabilities of NUnit, but I never thought about using them to test my items one by one. That's a nice idea, and I guess that the icky feeling I have is just that I am not used to doing it this way. I'll look into it.